# How to save changes to SQLiteStudio (3.4.3)

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert, create-table, date-arithmetic

I am trying to save my changes (code below) in all rows in 1 column by using the export option but my database is not affected. Date in my column is set to September and I successfully changed it to march but just in SQL editor. How do I save these changes?

```
select name,
DATE(datum, '-6 months')
as datum
from concerts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the column `datum` then you need an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE concerts 
SET datum = date(datum, '-6 months');
```

If you want to insert the rows in a different table then you need an `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO other_table (name, datum)
SELECT name, date(datum, '-6 months')
FROM concerts;
```

If you want to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
SELECT name, date(datum, '-6 months')
FROM concerts;
```